# AngularJS 1.6 + ES6 - $doCheck is called twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, components

I'm trying to propagate an event from a child component to a parent component using AngularJS.

I have a parent component as shown:

**parent.component.js**

```
import angular from 'angular';
import childComponent from './child/child.component'  

let parent = {
        template: require('./parent.view.html'),
        controller: 'parentController',
        controllerAs: 'parentCtrl',

    };

class parentController {
    constructor() {
          this.myvalue = 'default';
     }

    $doCheck(event) {            
        console.log('new myvalue:' + this.myvalue);
    }
}

const parentComponent = 'parent';

angular.module(parentComponent, [childComponent])
    .component('parent', parent)
    .controller('parentController', parentController);

export default parentComponent;
```

**parent.view.html**

```
<child changevalue="parentCtrl.myvalue = $event.myvalue"></child>
  <p>myvalue: {{parentCtrl.myvalue}}</p>
```

**child.component.js**

```
import angular from 'angular';

let child = {

    template: require('./child.view.html'),
    controller: 'childController',
    controllerAs: 'childCtrl',
    bindings:{        
        changevalue: '&'
    }

};

class childController {
    constructor() {
    }    

    triggerEvent() {        
        this.changevalue({$event: {myvalue: 'child1'}});
    }   

}

const childComponent = 'childComponent';

angular.module(childComponent, [])
    .component('child', child)
    .controller('childController', childController);

export default childComponent;
```

**child.view.html**

```
<button ng-click="childCtrl.triggerEvent()">Select</button>
```

Upon button click in child view, I'm successfully able to change `myvalue` in parent, as shown in the parent view.

However, this change **does not trigger** `$onChange()` method in `parent.component.js`.

Moreover, this change triggers `$doChange()` **twice**.

I want the button-click to trigger a method call only once.

What am I doing wrong ? Any guidance is earnestly welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Child component is more or less ok. One thing is that you must not use `$` - this is reserved for angular internal variables and methods. 
   This is your homemade event, so it should be without dollar.
2. You do not need controllerAs syntax for components - it is $ctrl by default and no point to change it.
3. In html it is better to avoid expressions like `ng-click="a = 2"`, use methods from start.
4. When you call method directly - you do not need $onCheck, $onChanges or whatever. $onChanges and $onCheck is to watch bindings changes - you will need them if you change something in parent and watch to watch these changes in child.

In the end you have:

```
let child = {

    template: require('./child.view.html'),
    controller: 'childController',
    bindings:{        
        changevalue: '&'
    }

};

class childController {
    constructor() {
    }    

    triggerEvent() {        
        this.changevalue({event: {myvalue: 'child1'}});
    }   

}

<button ng-click="$ctrl.triggerEvent()">Select</button>


let parent = {
        template: require('./parent.view.html'),
        controller: 'parentController',

    };

    class parentController {
        constructor() {
              this.myvalue = 'default';
         }

        setEvent(event) {
            this.myvalue = event.myvalue;            
            console.log('new myvalue:' + this.myvalue);
        }
    }


    <child changevalue="$ctrl.setEvent(event)></child>
      <p>myvalue: {{parentCtrl.myvalue}}</p>
```